# Opening a custom webpart created in 2005 in visual studio 2010

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, migration

We are migrating moss 2007 site to SharePoint 2010. I am faced with a challenge with manual migrating a custom webpart from Moss 2007 to SharePoint 2010. When i open the webpart created in visual studio 2005 in 2010 and try to build the solution. I get this error

> "The command ""c:\program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web
>   server extensions\14\bin\stsadm.exe" -o execadmsvcjobs" exited with
>   code 3."

Any guidence on how to tackle it?

**Update** -  Here is the data in the Project.default.target file

```
<PropertyGroup>
<PackageFile>name.wsp</PackageFile>
<TargetUrl>http://localhost</TargetUrl>
<ProjectDeploymentFilesFolder>DeploymentFiles</ProjectDeploymentFilesFolder>
<ProjectRootFilesFolder>RootFiles</ProjectRootFilesFolder>
<WssRootFilesFolder>"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14"</WssRootFilesFolder>


<!-- Modified 3/25/08 RHoward - tokenized system directory -->
<MAKECAB>"C:\WINDOWS\system32\makecab.exe"</MAKECAB>
<!-- End of 3/25/08 Modification -->
<STSADM>"c:\program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\bin\stsadm.exe"</STSADM>

<STSADM>"$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN\stsadm.exe"</STSADM>
<STSDEV>"C:\GDT_Tools\STSDev\stsdev.exe"</STSDEV>

<!-- Added 3/25/08 RHoward - Surrounded TargetName and SolutionDir with quotes to support spaces there -->
<REFRESH>$(STSDEV) /refresh "$(TargetName)" "$(SolutionDir)"</REFRESH>
<!-- End of 3/25/08 Add -->
<GACUTIL>"C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\gacutil.exe"</GACUTIL>
<ISSAPP_SCRIPT>CSCRIPT.EXE C:\WINDOWS\system32\iisapp.vbs</ISSAPP_SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run a x64 bit system (SharePoint 2010) so stsadm.exe is not located here

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\bin\stsadm.exe"

Update Microsoft.SharePoint.targets file to

"$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\bin\stsadm.exe"

Close the solution and re-open it.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: im a bit confused where you bought in the x86? i know its the same as the link i posted but spStacker stsadm is not referencing x86 like the file path your suggesting and the same as my link ;) , "error file not found" meaning he needs to find the file that is being reference and see if it exists, plus yes should be on x64 and 2005 should be targeting x64, his path indicates its x64 not x86

Comment: He was migrating from MOSS 2007 so there is possibility that the earlier solution built on x86 and the file may refer to the path with x86 directory. I have assumed on that basis only, haven't visited your link yet but will do now ;) I knew  it because same kind of thing happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this i think its the same issue :)

http://stsdev.codeplex.com/discussions/27623

asking the question in that area would get a better reponse too!

also

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/6b4753db-76d9-442a-9c35-8cc3a87f71bf

from the above link the error indicates

> "error file not found"

hope it helps :)

**EDIT**

can you change the code slightly to this?

```
<WssRootFilesFolder>$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14</WssRootFilesFolder>
```

also make sure that:

> c:\program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\14\bin\stsadm.exe

(stsadm.exe) exsist at that location?

If not then change that also to the location it should exsist, so it should look like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>     
<PackageFile>name.wsp</PackageFile>     
<TargetUrl>http://localhost</TargetUrl>     
<ProjectDeploymentFilesFolder>DeploymentFiles</ProjectDeploymentFilesFolder>     
<ProjectRootFilesFolder>RootFiles</ProjectRootFilesFolder>     
<WssRootFilesFolder>"$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14"</WssRootFilesFolder>     


<!-- Modified 3/25/08 RHoward - tokenized system directory -->     
<MAKECAB>"C:\WINDOWS\system32\makecab.exe"</MAKECAB>     
<!-- End of 3/25/08 Modification -->     
<STSADM>"$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\bin\stsadm.exe"</STSADM>     

<STSADM>"$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN\stsadm.exe"</STSADM>     
<STSDEV>"C:\GDT_Tools\STSDev\stsdev.exe"</STSDEV>     

<!-- Added 3/25/08 RHoward - Surrounded TargetName and SolutionDir with quotes to support spaces there -->     
<REFRESH>$(STSDEV) /refresh "$(TargetName)" "$(SolutionDir)"</REFRESH>     
<!-- End of 3/25/08 Add -->     
<GACUTIL>"C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\gacutil.exe"</GACUTIL>     
<ISSAPP_SCRIPT>CSCRIPT.EXE C:\WINDOWS\system32\iisapp.vbs</ISSAPP_SCRIPT>
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer - i tried is but still having the same error. any more suggestions? i habe updated the question

Comment: iv ammended the answer

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer update, after making the changes- am getting a different exist code error "The command ""c:\program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\bin\stsadm.exe" -o execadmsvcjobs" exited with code -1". two things i have noticed are not there in the mentioned links 1) gacutil inside "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\"  and stsdev.exe inside the link C:\GDT_Tools\STSDev\

Comment: ahh ok you need to find the correct locations on the server where they are and change the links to the correct location!

Comment: Hi - i have correected the gacutil path but the stsdev is no where to be found in the machine - seems like it is used for deployment in 2007..any suggestions?

Comment: ahh ok, stsdev is for sharepoint 2007, thats your problem :), http://stsdev.codeplex.com/ . I use wspbuilder. You need to install stsdev or wspbuilder! I would recommend wspbuilder that builds the wsp from any project you make be it a webpart or feature. From there you will have a wsp file that you can use to deploy to sharepoint 2010! unfortunatly stsdev is for sharepoint 2003 and 2007! http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/downloads/get/94507?releaseId=30858&ProjectName=wspbuilder can be used for 2010 and is still used by many for 2010!